# Arrange friends

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

We have for friends (**A**, **B**, **C**, and **D**) and we have 10 single rooms (*1*, *2*, *3*, *4*, *5*, *6*, *7*, *8*, *9*, *10*). The rooms are ordered in a row.

1. **A** and **B** always want to be in rooms that are neighbors
2. **C** and **D** always want to be in rooms that are neighbors
3. **A** and **C** always DO NOT want to be in rooms that are neighbors

How many ways there are to order the friends in the rooms?

I started to list all possible combinations in my opinion and I manage to list 196, so I am not sure if 196 is the right answer

However, mathematically I cannot get 196.

I am trying to calculate all the combinations to order 4 people in 10 rooms by this formula:

$n = 10$,
$k = 4$

$\binom{n}k$ = $\dfrac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$

Therefore

$\binom{10}4 = \dfrac{10!}{4!(10 - 4)!} = \dfrac{10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6!}{4! * 6!} = \dfrac{5040}{24} = 210$

However, these are all combinations without considering the requirements 1 from 3. I tried to calculate 1 to 3 and after that extract this number from 210 to get smaller numbers, but I do not know how to consider these orderings.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Try inclusion exclusion.  First treat $AB,CD$ as blocks with no exclusions.  Now treat $BA, CD$ as blocks only this time exclude $BACD$.  And so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this using stars and bars.

We first line up $A, B, C$ and $D$ in a row. Now as $A$ and $B$ must be neighbors, and $C$ and $D$ must be neighbors, We can assign them room numbers such that there can be some rooms to their left , some between $\{AB\}$ and $\{CD\}$ and some to their right. As there are $6$ rooms left, we are looking for non-negative solutions to,

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 6$

That is $ \displaystyle {6 + 3 - 1 \choose 3 -1 } = 28$

Now $A$ and $B$ can swap their places and still remain neighbors and so can $C$ and $D$. We can also swap the groups $\{AB\}$ and $\{CD\}$.

So number of solutions, given the first two conditions, is $~28 \cdot 8 = 224$

Now to take into account the third condition, we need to subtract those assignments of rooms where $A$ and $C$ were neighbors too. That can only happen if they are all assigned adjacent rooms and that leaves us to assign them rooms such that in total there are $6$ rooms in total to their left and right and none between them. There are obviously $7$ solutions as there can be $0 - 6$ rooms to the left and remaining to the right.

Now $A$ and $C$ can be neighbors in two ways - $~BACD~$ or $~DCAB$.

That leads to the final answer as $224 - 2 \cdot 7 = 210$.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to start with subtracting cases from 210 is probably not a good idea here. (in fact, you would need to be subtracting cases from $210 \cdot 24=5040$ in order to account for the ordering of A/B/C/D in those $4$ rooms) The best way by far to do this is to find the answer only assuming conditions 1 and 2, then subtract the cases that go against condition 3. Let us call the two neighboring rooms A and B want to be in together E, and the two for C and D, F. Now note the following process:

1. start with a row of 8 rooms
2. choose one of these rooms to be E, and the other to be F.
3. choose the ordering of A/B or B/A for E, and the ordering of C/D and D/C for F.
   This finds every combination that obeys rules 1 and 2. Note that ignoring rule 3 the answer would therefore be $8 \cdot 7 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 224$. In order to account for rule 3, we need to check all cases where E and F are next to each other, and subtract one for when we permute A/B and C/D such that A and C end up next to each other. The number of ways for E and F to end up next to each other is clearly $7 \cdot 2=14$, so we would subtract this from $224$ to end up with $210$.

Note: this is equal to $\binom{10}{4}$, but I'm pretty sure that's a coincidence.

Comment: I deleted my answer, I found 208 but I mistaken with the last part. Yours is correct.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The number of ways for $E$ and $F$ to be adjacent is $7$.  The number of ways $A$ and $B$ can be arranged within $E$ and $C$ and $D$ can be arranged within $F$ so that  $A$ and $C$ are adjacent is $2$.

Answer (score 1):

There are $8$ possible ordered combos of two from  $ABCD$ meeting the first two conditions, eg (AB)(CD), (AB)(DC) etc, of which $2$, need a mythical $X$ to meet all $3$ conditions,
$(BAX)(CD), (DCX)(AB)$ with $6,5$ rooms left available for the two types

The two "blocks" can be placed anywhere in the total of $8,7$ points available, thus $6\binom82 + 2\binom72 = 210$ ways